# Angular 2 how to retrieve and show simultaneous multiple objects from the server

Tags: angular

At the moment I am calling one single service that gives back one collection of objects "posts":

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Clients About Us</h1>
    <i *ngIf="postsLoading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x" style="color:white"></i>

    <div class="col-md-6 fix-height" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/people?random={{ post.id }}" alt="people">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{ user.name }}@ ={{ post.title }}</h4>
                <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to retrieve simultaneous users object for each post, so I could put in front off "@" user.name of the author of every post.
The example structure of user and posts objects are:

USERS:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
          "street": "Kulas Light",
          "suite": "Apt. 556",
          "city": "Gwenborough",
          "zipcode": "92998-3874",
          "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
          }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
          "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
          "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
          "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
      }
```

POSTS:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur o"
  }
```

So witch method should I use to obtain this user.name from the server at the same iteration when I have obtained posts?

It would be nice if somebody could explain how can I do that and point to what information should I learn in order to get this done, or share some example code.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
I have a function in the component that retrieves me the user object by Id

```
private loadUser(userId:any){
    return this._aboutusService.getUser(userId)
    .subscribe(
        user => this.user.name = user.name,
        response => {
            if (response.status == 404){
                this._router.navigate(['Home']);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

How should I get now only name in the html?

```
<div class="col-md-6 fix-height" *ngFor="let post of posts" >
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/people?random={{ post.id }}" alt="people">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ loadUser(post.userId)  }}@ {{ post.title }}</h4>
            <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how can i load user name on component init at put it in html?

Comment: does anybody can help me?

Comment: is my question hard to understand or why nobody respond?

Comment: can you make it shorter?

Comment: Well, you need to get the users using another (or several other) http requests from your component, and provide a way, in your component, to access the user based on the userId of the post. What is the concrete problem? What have you tried?